# RDA's plots with ggvegan: How can I change text position for arrows text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rda

Recently, I ran a RDA with `vegan` and, on sequence, I made RDA plots with `ggvegan` (Amazing!). However, I'm in trouble to edit arrow's text.

I used code below to generate attached image: [image]

```
library(devtools)
library(ggvegan)

cols <- c("Green", "Orange","Red","Blue")

Plot2 <- autoplot(resultado.rda_bio, arrows = TRUE,data = RDA ,colour = factor(Season), fill = factor(Season), label = TRUE, label.size = 3, shape = FALSE, loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue', loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3, scale= 0) +geom_point(data = RDA,aes(RDA1,RDA2,colour = Season),size=2,alpha=0.5)+
  ylim(-3,3.0)+ xlim(-2,2.0)+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0,slope = 0,linetype="dashed", size=0.8)+ geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0), linetype="dashed", size=0.8) + labs(x = "Axis 1 (13.8%)", y="Axis 2 (2.9%)") + theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(legend.justification = c(0,0), axis.text = element_text(family = "Arial",  colour = "black", size = 20),
        axis.title = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 25),
        text = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 20))

Plot2 + scale_colour_manual(values = cols, limits = c("Autumn", "Spring", "Summer", "Winter"))
```