# How to add environmental variable to DCA plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I would like to plot an environmental variable on a ggplot2 version of a DCA plot.

I have some code where I extract species and data scores from `vegan` and then plot them up in ggplot2. I am having trouble trying to work out how I can get my environmental variable SWLI to plot as an arrow - something like this [RDA's plots with ggvegan: How can I change text position for arrows text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265622/rdas-plots-with-ggvegan-how-can-i-change-text-position-for-arrows-text) (or see PCA example here https://www.rpubs.com/an-bui/vegan-cheat-sheet)

[image]

Can anybody help?

```r
#DCA Plot

library(plyr)
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
library(cluster)
library(ggfortify)
library(factoextra)


#read in csv and remove variables you don't want to go through analysis
regforamcountsall<-read_csv("regionalforamcountsallnocalcs.csv")
swli<-read_csv("DCAenv.csv")


rownames(regforamcountsall)<-regforamcountsall$Sample

regforamcountsall$Sample = NULL
regforamcountsall$Site=NULL
regforamcountsall$SWLI=NULL

#check csv
regforamcountsall

#run ordination

ord<-decorana(regforamcountsall)

#get species scores 

summary(ord)

#get DCA values of environmental variable
ord.fit <- envfit(ord ~ SWLI, data=swli, perm=999)
ord.fit

plot(ord, dis="site")
plot(ord.fit)

#use this summary code to get species scores for DCA1 and DCA2


#put species scores values in from ord plot summary stats 
species.scores<-read.csv("speciescores.csv")


species.scores$species <- row.names(species.scores)

#Using the scores function from vegan to extract the sample scores and convert to a data.frame
data.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(ord))  

# create a column of groupings/clusters, from the rownames of data.scores
data.scores$endgroup <- as.factor(pam(regforamcountsall, 3)$clustering) 

#getting the convex hull of each unique point set
find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(data.scores$DCA1, data.scores$DCA2), ]
hulls <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(unique(data.scores$endgroup))){
  endgroup_coords <- data.scores[data.scores$endgroup == i,]
  hull_coords <- data.frame(
    endgroup_coords[chull(endgroup_coords[endgroup_coords$endgroup == i,]$DCA1,
                          endgroup_coords[endgroup_coords$endgroup == i,]$DCA2),])
  hulls <- rbind(hulls,hull_coords)
}


data.scores$numbers <- 1:length(data.scores$endgroup)




regforamcountsall<-read_csv("regionalforamcountsallnocalcs.csv")
rownames(regforamcountsall)<-regforamcountsall$Sample

data.scores$Site<-regforamcountsall$Site
data.scores$SWLI<-regforamcountsall$SWLI
data.scores
#DCA with species 

data.scores$Site <- as.character(data.scores$Site)


library(scico)

dca <- ggplot() + 
  # add the point markers
  geom_point(data=data.scores,aes(x=DCA1,y=DCA2,colour=SWLI,pch=Site),size=4) + geom_point(data=species.scores,aes(x=DCA1,y=DCA2),size=3,pch=3,alpha=0.8,colour="grey22") +
  # add the hulls and labels - numbers position labels
  geom_polygon(data = hulls,aes(x=DCA1,y=DCA2,fill=endgroup), alpha = 0.25) +
  #geom_text(data=data.scores,aes(x=DCA1-0.03,y=DCA2,colour=endgroup, label = numbers))+
  geom_text(data=species.scores,aes(x=DCA1+0.1,y=DCA2+0.1, label = species))+
  #look this up
  geom_segment(data=ord.fit,aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend=DCA1,yend=DCA2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_color_scico(palette = "lapaz")+
  coord_fixed()

dca
  
  
#regforamcountsall data
structure(list(Sample = c("T3LB7.008", "T3LB7.18", "T3LB7.303", 
"WAP 0 ST-2", "T3LB7.5", "LG120"), T.salsa = c(86.63793102, 68.5897436, 
70.39274924, 5.199999999, 79.15057916, 44.40000001), H.wilberti = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.386100386, 9.399999998), Textularia = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.4), T.irregularis = c(2.155172414, 10.25641026, 7.854984897, 
0, 2.702702703, 0), P.ipohalina = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), J.macrescens = c(4.741379311, 
5.769230769, 4.833836859, 5.800000001, 8.108108107, 5.400000001
), T.inflata = c(6.465517244, 15.38461538, 16.918429, 83.2, 5.791505794, 
40.4), S.lobata = c(0, 0, 0, 2.300000001, 0, 0), M.fusca = c(0, 
0, 0, 3.499999999, 3.861003862, 0), A.agglutinans = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), A.exiguus = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), A.subcatenulatus = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P.hyperhalina = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SWLI = c(200, 
197.799175, 194.497937, 192.034776, 191.746905, 190.397351), 
    Site = c("LSP", "LSP", "LSP", "WAP", "LSP", "LG")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#data.scores
structure(list(DCA1 = c(-1.88587476921648, -1.58550534382589, 
-1.59816311314591, -0.0851161831632892, -1.69080448670088, -1.14488987340879
), DCA2 = c(0.320139736602921, 0.226662031865046, 0.230912045301637, 
-0.0531232712001122, 0.272143119753744, 0.0696939776869396), 
    DCA3 = c(-0.755595015095353, -0.721144380683279, -0.675071834919103, 
    0.402339366526422, -0.731006052784081, 0.00474996849420783
    ), DCA4 = c(-1.10780013276303, -0.924265835490466, -0.957711953532202, 
    -0.434438970032073, -0.957873836258657, -0.508347000558056
    ), endgroup = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "factor"), numbers = 1:6, Site = c("LSP", 
    "LSP", "LSP", "WAP", "LSP", "LG"), SWLI = c(200, 197.799175, 
    194.497937, 192.034776, 191.746905, 190.397351)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

#species.scores

structure(list(species = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), DCA1 = c(-2.13, 
-1.6996, -2.0172, -0.9689, 1.0372, -0.3224), DCA2 = c(0.342, 
-0.8114, 0.3467, -0.3454, 2.0007, 0.9147)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not sure if you are asking to resolve the fact that you cannot install it, but I'll address that: it is not on CRAN, so `install.packages("ggvegan")` will not work. To install it, you will need to do what the [github page](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan) says: `remotes::install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")` (can also use `devtools::install_github`).

Comment: Hi I already tried both of the second methods after realising it wasn't on CRAN and neither work, I either get a message saying: Skipping install of 'ggvegan' from a github remote, the SHA1 (4bc6ee99) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation and when I type force=TRUE nothing happens?

Comment: If `install_github` says *"has not changed since last install"*, then it appears to be installed. Why do you think that it won't install if it *is* installed? Have you tried `library(ggvegan)`, and does it produce errors?

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't understand what the error was telling me, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: FYI, I suggested an edit to your question to address code-blocks and the image (c.f., https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Namely, code blocks can use code "fences" which are the three backticks `\`\`\``, but they must be on their own line. The first fence can optionally include a language hint, but it must still be on its own line. Just a suggestion for clearing up how the question looks.

Comment: Thank you, they are some useful hints and tips :)

Comment: I think you have to start with *computing* the arrow for SWLI. Your text is rambling and unfocused, but I didn't see anything that computes the arrow. SWLI has several numeric values, and the arrow shows the direction to which these values increase most strongly (that is the gradient of linear trend surface), and the values you need are the coordinates of the endpoint of that arrow. Normally we use `vegan::envfit()` to get those coordinates. BTW, you should **absolutely** use `coord_fixed()` in ordination plots: the axes must be scaled equally.

Comment: Hi yes, sorry I figured that out this morning using: ord<-decorana(regforamcountsall)
#get DCA values of environmental variable
ord.fit <- envfit(ord ~ SWLI, data=swli, perm=999)
ord.fit

plot(ord, dis="site")
plot(ord.fit)

Comment: Multiply the coordinates with a constant to extend the arrow. The arrow will be drawn from the origin, but DECORANA may use shifted origin at the lower left corner instead of the true origin. If that is the case (vegan does not default to this false origin), you should use `position` argument in your `geom_segment` to move the arrow.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is what I needed.